# how to restore session in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session

I made a website in .net 4.0, In which user first login and redirect to dashboard page, After login there are 8 pages in user panel and a logout button in master page. I want to store on the page on which user logout and also when next time he login, his session will be restored(redirect to same page from where he logout) .
anyone can give me any hint ??

Comment: With "session restored", do you mean you only want the user to automatically return to the page where he left last time, or do you also want Session values to be restored??

Comment: I'm not sure if a session is the right way of storing this information. I'd probably do this in the database or alternatively in a cookie/jStorage object and redirect on login with JavaScript..

Comment: @RoyDictus I only want the user to automatically return to the page where he left last time

Comment: And do you want that regardless of which machine/browser the user uses? I mean, suppose I use your application today at work, and tomorrow I log in to your application at home. Then what happens?

Comment: @RoyDictus I want to store session valu in database so it no matters from where userlogin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing sessions with `Session`s... `Session` is an ASP.NET class that is available to every page provided you have Session support activated in your application (it is on by default, and stores its values in *memory* by default). But these `Session`s time out; after a certain period of inactivity -- say, 15 minutes -- the server clears the memory.

What you mean is just a session: the user logs in, does stuff and then logs out.

In order to automatically return to the last page he was on when he logged out, all you need to do is have the Log out button's code store the `Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri` string in the database. So just have that button's `Click` event handler in your codebehind store that value along with the user's ID.

Then the code behind of the Login button's `Click` event can simply retrieve that value and `Response.Redirect` to that Uri.

Comment: Thanks Roy you answer me exactly what I want , Thanks for better explaining the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

[Request.Url.AbsoluteUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri.aspx)

And store that in a session.

```
Session["LastVisitedPage_" + userId] = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

Comment: Thanks Darren your answer work for me, also roy gives a better explanation of your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use Request.Url to get the url of the current page. When the user clicks on the log out button, store the current url in the database. Next time the user logs in, retrieve the url from the database and redirect to it.

Comment: Thanks for replaying Ryan

Answer (score 2):

**To logout:**

```
 Session.abandon();
```

**To store session:**

```
 Session["name"] = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```